# The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: flask, server

it shows the function related to root url i.e. ('/') but if i write @app.route('/home') it gives me that error

Comment: Did you reload your app after you added the `/home` route? And can you paste all of the code in your app.py file?

Comment: I had reloaded it. I will try your suggestion. I think I have got the actual problem. **the flask server is still running** in spite of closing the editor and all code related stuff it shows me the output for '/' root url. I tried the change the contents but still it shows earlier returned data. that means it is running somewhere else. I have to find it where it is running...in the background!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on your clarifying comments, it appears your browser is accessing a previous version of your app server.

I have run into this problem myself when using the PyCharm IDE. On Windows, the way to shut down these old versions of the server is to press either `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` or `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` (Windows 10) to view your list of running processes. Then scroll down until you see processes named `Python` and shut them all down.

Comment: ---1  Delete running old instances of phyton exe  ---2  in edit option provide script path =app.py and parametes =FLASK_APP=app.js and select pip interpreter as project defaul

Comment: This also works on Azure Web Service, when ever anyone gets this type of error go to home page of your azure portal and simply restart the Web Service by hovering mouse over the resource and clicking restart.

Comment: Thank you. I've just backed out a load of changes thinking one of them was causing this even though I knew that it had worked previously. Restarted PyCharm and it worked. Will remember this one.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if it's due to some other python application running or something, but when I was a beginner in Flask I got a similar error to you.

I wrote `app.route('/')` instead of `@app.route('/')` (I missed the `@` symbol).

See whether it's the case for your code.

Answer (score 3):

You should have written @app.route('/home/'). That fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Definitely this answer for me, seems to also match the question exactly

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem: is to switch this instruction

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True ,port=8080,use_reloader=False)
```

as in the example bellow

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request                     
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="template")          
                                                          
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True ,port=8080,use_reloader=False) 
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
   query = request.form.get('query1')
   selected = request.form.get('query')
   if (not query or not selected):
       return 'failure'
   processed_text = query.upper()
   return render_template('sucess.html')
```

to the end of your script (same example):

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request
 app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="template")

 @app.route("/")
 def hello():
     return render_template('index.html')


 @app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
 def register():
     query = request.form.get('query1')
     selected = request.form.get('query')
     if (not query or not selected):
        return 'failure'
     processed_text = query.upper()
     return render_template('sucess.html')

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True ,port=8080,use_reloader=False)
```

UPDATE---------------------------------

You should also take care of the local file. Please put them in the statistic field then use url_for from the Flask framework to create a correct URL

```html
<div style = "text-align: center;">
  <a href="{{ url_for('static',filename=path)}}">
    <button class="slide_from_bottom button">check here </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially tried with @app.route("/hello") where the function I defined inside was def hello():
return "some statement"
this gave me the error stated above, I removed "/hello" and tried with "/" this resolved the issue for me.
p.s(I did this in pycharm and os is windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after deploying a legacy **Python Flask** application to **Azure App Service** for my team.

I was getting the error:

> Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the URL I was entering wasn't the right one. Apparently, the developers did not set a root route, so instead of this:

```
https://my-website.com
```

You will have to specify the path to the resource you want, so we will have:

```
https://my-website.com/my-desired-path
```

**That's all**

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed `@` before the `app.route('/')`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style = "text-align: center;">
  <a href="{{ url_for('static',filename=path)}}">
    <button class="slide_from_bottom button">check here </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error just recently. This is what I did and it worked:

```
from flask import Flask,  render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The "about" HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>Learn about our company.</p>
    <**a href="{{ url_for('about') }}"**>About</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, in the updated "about.html" file, I have added an anchor tag with the **href** attribute set to **{{ url_for('about') }}**, which uses the Flask **url_for** function to generate the URL for the about page based on the route specified in your Flask app. It ensures that the URL in your HTML code matches the route specified in your Flask app.
Here is the [Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/templates/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you switch it to '/home', '/' does not exist anymore and thus gives a 404 error. (flask default is '/')

Answer (score 0):

This error can be occur due to period `@app.route("/.", methods =['GET'])`
Correct one is `@app.route("/", methods =['GET'])`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but it was immediately solved once I restarted my laptop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your browser change the url from:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000`

To:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/about`

whatever you are adding `@app.route("/about")` here