# Flask- The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask

I think this is a simple problem but I am kind of stuck here.

I am trying to deploy keras model in Flask. My main propose is to practice api.

But I am getting this error continuously whenever I tried to open given local host id.

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Did I miss anything in my code?

I have mentioned my code below:

```
from numpy.lib.twodim_base import tri
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import flask
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import joblib
import csv
import codecs
import warnings




def warn(*arg, **kwargs):
    pass

warnings.warn = warn

#initialize the flask application

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

#load the pre-trained model

def define_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('./model/anomaly_model.h5')
    return print("Model is loaded")


limit = 10

@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])

def submit():
    #initialize the data dictionary that will be returned in the response
    data_out = {}
    #load the data file from our endpoint
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        #read the data file
        file = flask.request.files['data_file']
        if not file:
            return "No file submitted"
        data = []
        stream, = codecs.iterdecode(file.stream, 'utf-8')
        for row in csv.reader(stream, dialect=csv.excel):
            if row:
                data.append(row)
                
        #convert input data to pandas dataframe
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0], inplace=True)
        df2 = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
        df2 = df2.astype(np.float64)
        
        #normalize the data
        scaler = joblib.load('./data/combined.csv')
        X = scaler.transform(df2)
        X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    
        data_out['Analysis'] = []
        preds = model.predict(X)
        preds = preds.reshape(preds.shape[0], preds.shape[2])
        preds = pd.DataFrame(preds, columns=df2.columns)
        preds.index = df2.index
        
        scored = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.index)
        yhat = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.reshape[2])
        scored['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(yhat - preds), axis=1)
        scored['Threshold'] = limit
        scored['Anomaly'] = scored['Loss_mae'] > scored['threshold']
        print(scored)
    
    #determine of an anomaly was detected
    
    triggered = []
    for i in range(len(scored)):
        temp = scored.iloc[i]
        if temp.iloc[2]:
            triggered.append(temp)
    print(len(triggered))
    if len(triggered) > 0:
        for j in range(len(triggered)):
            out = triggered[j]
            result = {"Anomaly": True, "Value":out[0], "filename":out.name} 
            data_out["Analysis"].append(result)
    else:
        result = {"Anomaly":"No Anomalies Detected"}
        data_out["Analysis"].append(result)
    print(data_out)
        
    return flask.jsonify(data_out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(("* Loading the Keras model and starting the server ...."
          "Please wait until the server has fully started before submitting"))
    define_model()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Actually I am new in Flask.
This is my first attempt.  I also tried to give app.run(host='0.0.0.0') but didn't work for me. Can I get some help???

This is the log from terminal:

```
* Loading the Keras model and starting the server ....Please wait until the server has fully started before submitting
2021-12-27 16:29:45.158086: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Model is loaded
 * Serving Flask app 'implimentation' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
* Loading the Keras model and starting the server ....Please wait until the server has fully started before submitting
2021-12-27 16:29:49.283527: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Model is loaded
Model is loaded
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 114-980-010
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021 16:05:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021 16:05:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021 16:05:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021 16:05:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Hoping for some help

Thanks

Comment: what does the server logs say? after you run `python app.py` ?

Comment: It comes like this: [27/Dec/2021 16:07:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: I will add full log , give me a second.

Comment: i mean, when you start the server.. the server says "serving at xyz " right?

Comment: I added the log. could you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try change `@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])` to `@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])`. That is, remove the `submit`. When you run the program, the default location is http://127.0.0.1:5000/, but you are attempting to access http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit.

Either access http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit each time, or remove the submit from the url, which is easier, and access the default location each time.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953621/flask-404-not-found) is fairly similar.

Comment: This one helped. But I don't see any result in page except {}.

Comment: That may be a problem with the other code. If it returns a value other than no URL found (ie an expected value), then the flask routing is working.

Comment: I couldn't print the output in flask page. I will upload a new question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.

The only route you have is the `/submit` POST route.

You are getting that error because you are hitting a `/`(GET) route instead of `/submit`(POST)

Either add a new route to see your server up and running like so

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return 'home'
```

or using a tool such as postman, hit the `/submit` route as a POST request.

Remember also that the port is 5000.

Comment: I got it, I tried but it only print's {} in my web app. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

the /submit endpoint is not a regular GET request that you can hit by typing http://localhost:5000/submit.

Its clearly expecting a file upload. Make a dummy frontend with a upload file button, or use Postman to create a Post request with necessary flags to upload a file, and ofcourse, do provide the file path