# Python flask on IIS deployment error - The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, iis

I am trying to deploy Python flask app in IIS,

```
`python Code
from flask import Flask
# Create a Flask application instance
app = Flask(__name__)
# Define a route and a corresponding function
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
# Run the application if this script is executed directly
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()`
```

```
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SampleModulehandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\WebApplications\SampleApp\samplevenv\Scripts\python.exe|D:\WebApplications\SampleApp\samplevenv\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="flaskiis.app" /> <!-- {name_of_file}.{name_of_flask_app}-->
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\WebApplications\SampleApp" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>`
```

I tried running from command prompt using python flaskiis.py and it is working fine without any issues doesn't work in IIS. Facing error -  The requested URL was not found on the server.If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Same error you can use as reference: [Flask- The requested URL was not found on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492661/flask-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-the-server). If this still can't solve the problem, you can check whether there are related error messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: No luck, I have add methods=['GET','POST'] still same error. No evenvwr logs as well.