# "URL Not found error" when trying to load my flask application in browser window

Tags: python, flask

Below is my code. I want to convert excel file to json via my flask application. After running the code, while trying to load up the flask URL in browser, localhost gives the following error:

`404 not found error - The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again`

What do I need to do? Below is my application code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import flask_excel as excel


app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return jsonify({"result": request.get_array(field_name='file')})
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload an excel file</title>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <p><input type=file name=file><input type=submit value=Upload>
   </form>
    '''

@app.route("/export", methods=['GET'])
def export_records():
    return excel.make_response_from_array([[1,2], [3, 4]], "csv",
                                          file_name="export_data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hi, does this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949338/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-the-server-if-you-entered-the-url-manually-p
If that does not help you, try putting this instead of your app.run(),
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help but neither of them worked

Comment: I run your code, it works fine, please comment here, which api you called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've defined your app logic under the route `@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])` and you do not have any logic defined under your base address: `@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])`, you have to load your application using this as your URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload
```

And if you are using any other host address or port number in your flask application, you have to change your URL as:

```
http://Your_flask_IP_Address:Port_Number/upload
```

Please do comment if this works. Cheers!