# Flask and Python: dynamically printing table on clicking a value from dropdown

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a mysql table and in the html page i have a dropdown list. I want to print selected rows from the Myqsl table based on the value selected (Hyundai, Maruthi, Toyota, Ford) from the dropdown menu.

I have my script home.py as:

```
class Table(db.Model):

 name=db.Column(db.String,primary_key=True)
 color= db.Column(db.String(100))
 Engine=db.Column(db.String(200))
 Adress=db.Column(db.String(200))
 Car_type=db.Column(db.String(200))


@app.route('/Home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Home():
 cars = ['Hyundai', 'Maruthi', 'Toyota', 'Ford']
 if request.method=='POST':
    manus=request.form
    return redirect(url_for("newpage.html", classi=manus))
 return render_template("Home.html",   cars=cars)#

@app.route('/newpage/<classi>' )  

def user(classi):
 datas=Table.query.filter_by(Table.Car_type == classi).all()
 return render_template("newpage.html", datas=datas)
```

I have my Home html page as:

```
<form method="POST " action="/newpage">
<select name="Cartypes" </p>
<option value="{{cars[0]}}" selected>{{cars[0]}}</option>
{% for t in cars[1:] %}
  <option value="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And i have my newpage.html as:

```
 {% for row in datas %}
   

    <tr>
   

        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.color }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Engine }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Adress }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Car_type }}</td>
        

   
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:
**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950213/5675325)?

Comment: Thanks Tiago. I have not seen earlier. But i went through it now. I did restart my flask server.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: No. It still shows the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to implement **GET** method in your form request.

Next thing is the form won't automatically submit without a button of submit type. In order to do that you could take help of javascript.

In your flask app:

```
@app.route('/newpage' )  
def user():
  classi = request.args.get("Cartypes")
  datas=Table.query.filter(Table.Car_type == classi).all()
  return render_template("newpage.html", datas=datas)
```

In your home.html

```
<form method="GET" action="/newpage">
  <select name="Cartypes" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Model</option>
    {% for t in cars %}
      <option value="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</form>
```

After you change on the dropdown it send a request to your flask server with request like:

`http://localhost/newpage/?Cartypes=type_here`.

The flask server search for the **Cartypes** paramater, queries it and return the queryset to the html.

Comment: Thank you Pax! I get the following error now: TypeError:filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: In the url i get as:http://localhost/newpage?Cartypes=Ford

Comment: Try `datas=Table.query.filter_by(Table.Car_type=classi).all()`

Comment: It worked nonw. I changed "filter_by" to "filter". Thank you Pax and Tiago!!

Comment: Yes. Thing were meant to be that way. This tells the user he is currently seeing Product with **cartype=ford**

Comment: Welcome. I hope you would valid this answer too.:D

Comment: Try datas=Table.query.filter_by(Table.Car_type=classi).all(). I tried this earlier but it showed error.

Comment: Yes, I will validate the answer.

Comment: Please edit as datas=Table.query.filter(Table.Car_type == classi)